# UNIX : in a line like below ( output of ps ) , i need to extract just the server name ( that comes after -Dweblogic.Name=)

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

UNIX : in a line like below ( output of ps ) , i need to extract just the server name ( that comes after -Dweblogic.Name=)

user 25765 25711  0 Jun11 ?        10:21:15 /opt/bea/wls1033/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/var/prod/logs/DEVA/DEVA_SDAT202A/gc_DEVA_.log -Dweblogic.Name=**DEVA_SDAT202A** -Djava.security.policy=/opt/bea/wls1033/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/usr/prod/domains/DEVA/servers/DEVA_SDAT202A/data/nodemanager/boot.properties -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=false -Dweblogic.ReverseDNSAllowed=false -Dsdat.config=/usr/prod/domains/DEVA/sdat/config/sdat.properties

Comment: See [ask] and try again.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
ps ...parameters... | sed -e "s/^.* -Dweblogic.Name=\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/"
```

What that does is use sed to delete all the stuff from the beginnging of the string (^) up to and including "-Dweblogic.Name=" as well as all the stuff after the value of weblogic.Name until the end of the string ($).

Answer (score -1):

Perl probably isn't the best tool, but if you prefer it something like this will work. I'm assuming the server name can't have spaces in it. It'll exclude lines that don't match. You can filter it through grep first for that if you find it easier.

```
ps whatever_args | perl -ne "print \"$1\n\" if (/Dweblogic.Name=([^\s]+)/)"
```

I tested on Windows hence the \" but I think unix is more accepting of single quotes on the command line.

Comment: *"Perl probably isn't the best tool"* Some people would disagree! What language do you prefer for text manipulation?

Comment: If someone isn't interested in programming as a whole they might get a lot more mileage out of learning sed, awk, or related tools.

Comment: That is a salesman's phrase. Of course "anyone" *might* get a lot more mileage out of "anything", but what would they be doing with sed or awk if they had no interest in programming? People are mostly interested either in learning new skills or in paying for someone who has those skills already. Stack Overflow has revealed a third category of people who have no wish to learn but refuse to pay a fee. I don't think it's a great idea to encourage anyone who puts themselves in that category.